# Как поместить адрес в переменную?

Tags: c, указатели

Как поместить адрес в переменную int, не указатель?
Мне нужно работать с адресом как с числом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На C - просто привести к данному типу:

```
int x;
int y = (int)&x;
```

Только учите, что, например, на 64-разрядной платформе указатель может не поместиться в `int`, и нужно использовать другой тип.

В `<stdint.h>` описан такой тип - `intptr_t` - целочисленный тип, на данной платформе достаточный для размещения значения указателя. Используйте его.

Comment: Только для адресов всё же лучше использовать беззнаковый тип `uintptr_t`. А знаковые - для размеров и смещений.